# How to make a PHP script react in real time to a database insertion?

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, ipc

I have multiple PHP scripts running 24/7, each on different machines, that fetch information about users, from the Internet.

These users are in a table in a (postgresql) database. Every time a new user registers in the app, a new record is inserted in the table, which assigns it to one of the currently running PHP scripts (distributing the load evenly).

Is there a way so that the PHP script it has been assigned to can react in real time, in order to begin fetching information about the user immediately?

(The current setup I have is that each PHP script queries the table every 1 min, and checks if new users have been assigned to it... but more frequent queries increase database load, and in that 1 min window I am not fetching information from the newly added user.)

Comment: The short answer, "No." The long answer, start looking at Node.js.

Comment: Check postgres manual for `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`.

Comment: BTW Why didi you tag the question with `mysql`?

Comment: I'm also interested in a possible solution for `MySQL`, in case there is a super-easy way to accomplish this.

Comment: LISTEN / NOTIFY in five minutes http://www.pomm-project.org/news/using-postgresql-notify-in-5-minutes.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this example of PHP code for postgres `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-get-notify.php

Postgres man on `LISTEN/NOTIFY`:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-notify.html
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-listen.html

Comment: But I'd still have to call `pg_get_notify()` every 1 min to see if new notifications have been issued, wouldn't I? I assume this is more lightweight than querying a table and that I can increase the poll frequency?

Comment: @hallaplay835 No, you don't need to call it every minute. It will block the script execution until it receives a notification. If you don't want to get the script blocked then there are workarounds which require polling a socket. Anyway, just google for the examples. `LISTEN/NOTIFY` is definitely a way to go for PostgreSQL real time events.

Answer (score 0):

Trigger an HTTP request from a `sys_exec()` launch from an **SQL trigger** ? But it's seems overkill.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER `test_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `test`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

SET @exec_var = sys_exec('/usr/bin/php /myApp/after_insert.php')
END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

I know it's not a postgres script but it should work.

--- EDIT ---

And after in `after_insert.php` :

```
function httpPost($url, $data)
{
    $curl = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    return $response;
}
```

sources :
[How to make an HTTP Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Comment: This would launch `after_insert.php`... which would issue an HTTP request? So the HTTP request is sent to the machine where the originally running PHP script is... and how would it be alerted?

Comment: Hum, yes why not ?
SQL Trigger -> sys_exec -> after_insert.php -> http post to your remote script. I will update my answer

Comment: My PHP script `A.php` runs on a machine where there is not a web server. In case I installed one, the request would be handled by another PHP script `B.php` that would have to communicate somehow with `A`. How? [Inter-process communication](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-socket-pair.php)? Maybe a [tick handler](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.declare.php)? Are you sure this is more efficient than querying the table continuously?

Comment: I would recommend to avoid using such solutions which depend on execution of external programs. It is not safe, not efficient, not portable and not cool! Make use of `LISTEN/NOTIFY` feature instead.

Comment: I think it's the most efficient @pumbo, maybe not cool, but efficient, portable and safe. Safer than an open endpoint pointing on a select query.
Why don't install a web server ? You just add an entry in your `iptables` on the `A` server receiving the query from the ip of the `A` one and an `nginx` exposing your `B.php` script. Maybe I don't really understand the problem ... There is no IPC or tick handler to use ...